# Regex match all Vular Fractions

Tags: javascript, regex

There are 18 vulgar fraction symbols
and I would like to match them in regex.

Is this the best way listing them all

```
/[¼½¾⅐⅑⅒⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞]/
```

Answer (score 13):

They are Unicode characters.

¼½¾ have the continuous Unicode values (from `\u00BC` to `\u00BE`), and the rest (⅐⅑⅒⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞) have the continuous Unicode values (from `\u2150` to `\u215E`).

You can use this `[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]`.